# Is there somebody who knows how to send data from a webhosted webdomain to a ESP32 using http get request?

Tags: http, arduino, esp32

The question is, how can we send data from the Webhosting domain to our esp32 with an HTTP GET Request?

Comment: why not make the request from the esp32 to Internet?

Comment: thx for your response. I am not sure I give the correct description. We have a MySQL database on our website and we need to get access to the MySql-database data from our ESP32. Note: our website is not hosted on the ESP32!

Comment: you have some misconception. data are are usually requested by client devices since a server in Internet can't simply reach devices in local networks. Stack Overflow doesn't send this page to your browser without the request from the browser

Comment: HTTP is for a client (that is, a browser, a device, a client) to make a request to a server for data (a client-server architecture). If what you are looking for is for server to "inform" devices out in the field, then you need something like "publish-subscribe architecture, e.g. MQTT), where the devices subscribe to a topic and a server can publish a topic whenever it needs to communicate with device(s).

Answer (score 1):

If the ESP32 is behind a local network this is not possible.

If you want to initiate a request from outside of the network where the ESP32 is, you must put the esp32 to the internet.

You can port forward the ESP32's ip address/port on your router. That way you can reach the esp32 via your router's public ip. That way you can do any HTTP request to the ESP32 from anywhere in the world.

I warn you however that this method is not recommended since your network will be open to the outside world on the port you opened.

An other way is to use some kind of a tunnel server.
There are solutions for that such as **ngrok** or **husarnet**

I would recommend you to create a server somewhere in the cloud and fetch the desired data from that server with the esp32. Since you can request data inside your local network from the outside.